# What formula should i use on if and and

Tags: windows-10

question: if experience is more than 10 years and basic salary is less than 3000 and sales region is bedok then bonus is 1000, else if experience is more than 10 years and basic salary is less than 3000 and sales region is other region then bonus is 500, else bonus is 0
I have tried but result is all 0

Comment: What application are you trying to use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 2):

For both Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets:

The formula you should use is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(EXPERIENCE>10, SALARY<3000), IF(REGION="bedok", 1000, IF(REGION<>"bedok", 500)), 0)
```

You **must** enter this formula in the BONUS cell.

Where:
**EXPERIENCE** is the cell where the experience is written to.
**SALARY** is the cell where the basic salary is written to.
**REGION** is the cell wehre the region is written to.

The statement works as follows:

```
IF(AND(EXPERIENCE>10, SALARY<3000)
```

If the experience is over 10 years **and** the salary is under 3000, then:

```
IF(REGION="bedok", 1000
```

If region is "bedok", set cell value to 1000, else:

```
IF(REGION<>"bedok", 500)), 0)
```

If region isn't bedok, set cell value to 500, else set value to 0.

In pseudo-code, it looks like this:

```
if experience > 10 and salary < 3000:
   if region == "bedok":
        bonus = 1000
    else if region != "bedok":
        bonus = 500
else:
    bonus = 0
```

This is what I understood to be your condition:
If someone has both more than 10 years of experience and salary of less than 3000, check if his region is "bedok" or something else. If the region is "bedok", set bonus to 1000, else if region is another region, set bonus to 500. Else, if that someone doesn't have more than 10 years of experience or has a salary of more than 3000, don't give any bonus (set bonu to 0).

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: thank for the comment but the answer is all 0 which I think is wrong, but nevermind I shall explore again

Comment: @AnnChaw Try the following: `IF(AND(EXPERIENCE>10, SALARY<3000), IF(REGION="bedok", BONUS=1000, IF(REGION<>"bedok", BONUS=500, BONUS=0)))` If that doesn't work, I have even one more way that you can try.

Comment: the answer come out become false

Comment: =IF(AND(D4>10, J4<3000), IF(E4="bedok", M4=1000, IF(E4<>"bedok", M4=500, M4=0)))

Comment: Then last try: `=IF(AND(EXPERIENCE>10, SALARY<3000, REGION="bedok"), BONUS=1000, IF(AND(EXPERIENCE>10, SALARY<3000, REGION<>"bedok"), BONUS=500, IF(OR(EXPERIENCE<10, SALARY>3000), BONUS=0)))` @AnnChaw

Comment: still the same..answer is false

Comment: @AnnChaw Fixed my answer. You need to remove `BONUS=` and my solution in the answer will work (the first one). And you need to enter the formula in the BONUS cell. I tested it now on Google sheets and it works. Check my answer again.